# Can't bind service implementation using DI inside function with ServiceBusTrigger parameter in .net core Azure Web Job

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a .net core console application I am going to deploy as an Azure web job. The purpose of the job is to listen for new messages in an Azure Service Bus Queue. I have set the listener up using a function containing the [ServiceBusTrigger] Attribute. I built a dummy implementation which just reads the latest message from the queue - this works without issue - the message is passed correctly from the service bus queue to my function.

When I try to go to the next level and add an interface parameter to the function to be injected by DI I get an error.

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException:
>   'Error indexing method 'Functions.ProcessMeasurementData'' 
>   InvalidOperationException: Cannot bind parameter 'service' to type
>   IProcessMeasurementService. Make sure the parameter Type is supported
>   by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure
>   Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the
>   registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
>   builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

This is my function. If I remove the parameter IProcessMeasurementService service it works with no issue running locally from Visual Studio 2019 (I haven't tried deploying to azure yet as a webjob), picking up new items as they are added to the Azure Service Bus Queue.

```
public class Functions
{
    public static async Task ProcessMeasurementData(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("process-measurement-data-queue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")] Message message,
    IProcessMeasurementService service)
    {
        try
        {

            var measurements = JsonConvert
                .DeserializeObject<List<CreateMeasurementInput>>
                    (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));

            await service.DoStuff(measurements);

            // log.LogInformation(message.ContentType);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

I think I am registering the service correctly, like this:

```
            {
                // Register application services
                services.AddSingleton<IProcessMeasurementService, ProcessMeasurementService>();
            });
```

This is my main function in its entirety.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();

        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((builder) =>
        {
            builder

                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        });


        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddServiceBus(x =>
            {
                x.MessageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
                {
                    AutoComplete = false
                };
            });

            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        });

        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddOptions();

            // Register application services
            services.AddSingleton<IProcessMeasurementService, ProcessMeasurementService>();
        });

        var host = builder.Build();

        using (host)
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

From googling it feels like the problem might be something to do with my nuget package version. I tried adding a file called "host.json" in case it was a known problem with azure function versions conflicting with extensions libraries. But it did nothing. I am not actually using AzureFunctions (serverless functions I mean) but I am clutching at straws at this stage.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

This is the host.json just in case this is the issue.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Here're my nuget versions installed

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.16" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Sources" Version="3.0.16" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change from static function method to an instance member and inject the service via constructor injection directly into the function class.

```cs
public class Functions {

    private readonly  IProcessMeasurementService service;

    public Functions (IProcessMeasurementService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public async Task ProcessMeasurementData(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("process-measurement-data-queue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")] Message message) 
    {
        try {

            var measurements = JsonConvert
                .DeserializeObject<List<CreateMeasurementInput>>
                    (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));

            await service.DoStuff(measurements);

            // log.LogInformation(message.ContentType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //...    
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right for two reasons: 1 - you cannot use dependency injection in static classes; 2 - even if you could, you cannot make the injection directly on its methods, you must pass through the constructor. However, I should add that some argue (it is not consensual) that Azure Functions must be static: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168659/azure-functions-should-functions-be-written-inside-static-classes